# redireccionar a una vista

Tags: laravel

Me encuentro restringiendo el acceso a mis rutas en `laravel` y lo estoy haciendo con un middleware así:

```
class Admin_middleware
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->check() && auth()->user()->rol=='admin')
    return $next($request);

    return redirect('/401');
}
}
```

Tengo en mi carpeta `views` una carpeta llamada `errors` la cual contiene 2 archivos `404.blade.php` y `401.blade.php` el caso es que al yo redireccionar siempre me muestra el error `404.blade.php` y no el que le estoy indicando porque?

Este es el codigo de mi blade:

```
    @extends('errors::illustrated-layout')

@section('code', '401')
@section('title', __('Permiso Denegado'))

@section('image')
<style>
    #apartado-derecho{
        text-align:center;
    }
    ul{
        text-decoration: none !important;
        list-style: none;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div id="apartado-derecho" style="background-color: #F5716C;" class="absolute pin bg-cover bg-no-repeat md:bg-left lg:bg-center">
    <h2>Accede con un usuario permitido</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
@endsection

@section('message', __('No tienes permiso para acceder a esta pagina.'))
```

Comment: Y tus rutas cómo están? Lo que estás diciendo es que se redirigan a la ruta `/401` pero muestranos la ruta de tu `web.php` y la función del controlador para ver cómo la haces.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que tienes una ruta de esta manera `/401`

```
Route::get('/401', function () {
    return view('errors.401');
});
```

Si no lo haces directamente en las rutas, utilizarías un controlador en el cual crearías la vista, y la retornarías:

```
Route::get('/401', 'ErrorsController@unauthorized');

....

public function unauthorized(){
    $view = 'errors.401';
    $view = View::make($view);
    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Hola, lo hago en la ruta pero igualmente al llamarla le pongo return `redirect()->route('401'); ` y me sigue retornando al 404

Comment: Has revisado que ambas vistas sean distintas? Intentaste hacerlo como en el ejemplo que te puse?